# How to Correctly Use .wrap() in Cypress

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress 3.3.1

As an example that others can test, consider the following code:

```
  cy.visit('https://google.com')

  cy.get('input[type=text]').each((el, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      cy.wrap(el).type('some text')
    }
  })

  cy.contains('Google Search').click()
```

For some reason `cy.contains('Google Search').click()` is not able to find the element.

If I call `cy.wrap('body')` before I call `.contains('Google Search')` that now works. Suggesting that if you wrap an element, it changes some global context, and then has to be reset. No mention of this in the docs as far as I can see.

This code works:

```
  cy.visit('https://google.com')

  cy.get('input[type=text]').each((el, index) => {
    if (index === 0) {
      cy.wrap(el).type('some text')
    }
  })

  cy.wrap('body')

  cy.contains('Google Search').click()
```

Are you supposed to 'reset' the context after using `wrap()` or am I misunderstanding how it should be used?

Comment: No, you're not supposed to. This seems like a bug, but the dynamics are a bit different - it's the `.each()` call that seems to change scope, not the `cy.wrap()` --- I've [reported it here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/4921).

Comment: @dwelle thanks for working this out. Very surprised that its actually the .each() thats causing the issue. Thanks for reporting as a bug and confirming I'm not going mad!! lol